# Send Data to Server with Spring api's

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

i want to send data to my Restful Spring web service from my android client by Spring api's but i got below exeption ca anyone help me?
for example i want to register a user to my server,on my server side i have register method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public boolean registerNewUser(@RequestParam(name = "user")User user){
    if(user!=null){
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory=HibenateConnection.connectingHibernate();
            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and on my client side i open connection in Asynctask Class like this:

```
@Override
protected ResponseHandler doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        serverResponse=new ServerResponse();
        result = restTemplate.getForObject(URL+conditions,tClass,params);
        serverResponse.singleResult=result;
        serverResponse.isReady=true;
        responseHandler.onServerRespond(serverResponse);
    }catch (Exception e){
        serverResponse.isReady=false;
        serverResponse.message=e.getMessage();
    }
    return responseHandler;
}
```

and i called this method on my Activity with my user:

```
public static void registerUser(User user,ResponseHandler responseHandler){
    String condition="/user_api/register?user=";
    new Core<Long>(condition,Long.class,responseHandler).execute(user);
}
```

i got Exeption at line `restTemplate.getForObject(URL+conditions,tClass,params);` in my Core AsynTask Class and the exeption is:

```
Could not create URI object: Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 192.168.1.2:/3000/user_api/register?user
```

my server Url is 192.168.1.2:3000

Comment: it looks like your url has extra `/` before port number or you just need to add `http://` before `192.168.1.2`

Comment: no my url port number that i put in getForObject() is :URL="192.168.1.2:3000"

Comment: it was protocol, right? always have this issue on my local machine) so annoying

Comment: yes its sooooo annoying  @varren

Comment: one other question...did you work with Sprin api befor? i want to send user to my server but nothing send to server and there is no expetion at server side or client side can you review body of my AsyncTask class again please @varren

Comment: If there is something wrong on server side or you are sending data that server can't understand, `serverResponse` should be like this https://i.gyazo.com/159e7f71de65f763730319273f3ec26d.png Usually i debug my server with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en and then try to write android part . I never used spring on android, but the problem can be with x-www-form-urlencoded or some other detail. The code you are showing looks fine to me.

Comment: no the error is on client side i find out error but cant solve it my user type include some Forignkey and when i try to send it jackson library cant serialize it i use jacksonignor annotation but its not work @varren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple, but usually hard to debug, because it is so easy to forget to add protocol part `http://` before local url `192.168.1.2`. So end url in your case should look like this:

```
URL="http://192.168.1.2:3000"
```